# How to plot a linear regression to a segment of a line

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics

I have some data plotted as lines with matplotlib that are 250 points long. I can fit the whole data sets. However, I wish to fit and plot a regression line to just the last 50 data points using least squares. What is the best approach? (My plot code below.)

```
j = 0
for line, rank in sortedSymbols:
    series = getattr(self, line)["CLOSE"]
    dates = pd.to_datetime(getattr(self, line)["DATE"]).dt.date
    ax.plot(dates.iloc[-250:], series.iloc[-250:]/series.iloc[-250] * (40+j), label = line)
    j += 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of different ways to do this. But without more information on your data structure and what exactly your looking for, this is one way it could be done. `np.polyfit()` (documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)) uses OLS regression on your sequential data in lists or arrays.

```
import numpy as np

j = 0
for line, rank in sortedSymbols:
    series = getattr(self, line)["CLOSE"]
    dates = pd.to_datetime(getattr(self, line)["DATE"]).dt.date

    #Calculate the slope and intercept of fitted curve based on last 50 datapoint using the values 
    #you plotted before with 1 specified for a linear best fit line
    slope, intercept = np.polyfit(dates.iloc[-50:].index,series.iloc[-50:]/series.iloc[-250] * (40+j),1)

    #plot the trend line
    ax.plot(dates.iloc[-50:],slope*dates.iloc[-50:].index+intercept,label=line)


    j += 10
```

Comment: Thanks, the data structure is a pandas dataframe created by importing a csv file that contains stock data (symbol, date, open, high, low, close, volume) like so: df = pd.read_csv(path + name) Is there any other info that would be helpful?

Comment: Depending on your dates (if they are `datetime` objects) you may need to convert to a numeric date. Otherwise this should work with a `pandas` dataframe. You may have to add `.values` to the end or `to_numpy` depending on your version.

Comment: .index worked for me. Edit your answer to include. ttfn