# Linear regression plot with pandas, matplotlib and dates?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

This is a follow up question to: [How to plot a linear regression to a segment of a line with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57014336/how-to-plot-a-linear-regression-to-a-segment-of-a-line-with-matplotlib)

The previous question used a pandas dataframe that resulted from a csv import that had an integer index. I now wish to switch to another pandas dataframe that has an index of dates.

Here is the original solution that works:

```
import numpy as np

j = 0
for line, rank in sortedSymbols:
    series = getattr(self, line)["CLOSE"]
    dates = pd.to_datetime(getattr(self, line)["DATE"]).dt.date

#Calculate the slope and intercept of fitted curve based on last 50 datapoint using the values 
#you plotted before with 1 specified for a linear best fit line
slope, intercept = np.polyfit(dates.iloc[-50:].index,series.iloc[-50:]/series.iloc[-250] * (40+j),1)

#plot the trend line
      ax.plot(dates.iloc[-50:],slope*dates.iloc[-50:].index+intercept,label=line)
```

and here is the info on the new dataframe:

> ```
> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
> DatetimeIndex: 250 entries, 2018-08-29 to 2019-08-27
> Data columns (total 8 columns):
> Open                250 non-null float32
> High                250 non-null float32
> Low                 250 non-null float32
> Close               250 non-null float32
> Volume              250 non-null float32
> Turnover            250 non-null float32
> Unadjusted Close    250 non-null float32
> Dividend            250 non-null float32
> dtypes: float32(8)
> memory usage: 19.8 KB
> ```

and here is the new code I am trying:

```
for line, rank in sortedSymbols:    
    series = getattr(self, line)["Close"]
    dates = series.index.to_pydatetime()
    name = self.etfToNames[line]
    if method != 'end':
        ax.plot(dates[-250:], series.iloc[-250:]/series.iloc[-250] * (start+level), label = name, color= clr[i])
        y = series.iloc[-1]/series.iloc[-250] * (start+level)
        ax.annotate(name, xy=(1,y), xytext=(6,0), xycoords = ax.get_yaxis_transform(),
                        textcoords="offset points", size=10, va="center")
        slope, intercept = np.polyfit(dates[-50:],
             series.iloc[-50:]/series.iloc[-250] * (start + level), 1)
        print(line, slope, intercept)
        ax.plot(dates[-50:], slope * series.iloc[-50:] + intercept, color= clr[i])
j += 10
```

Which fails like so:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Public\Portfolio\Python Scripts\sectorplot-etf.py", line
>   201, in 
>       a.plotSectors()   File "C:\Users\Public\Portfolio\Python Scripts\sectorplot-etf.py", line 105, in plotSectors
>       series.iloc[-50:]/series.iloc[-250] * (start + level), 1)   File "C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py",
>   line 589, in polyfit
>       x = NX.asarray(x) + 0.0 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'float'

I have tried every conversion I can think of and none has worked so far. Any clue as how to solve this?

Comment: I would change your date to an ordinal date.

Comment: Thanks, that was the trailhead I needed: dates = series.index.to_julian_date() does the trick